# Virutalscroll fails to display when used with *ngIf

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am using virtualScroll to display a big list of movies. I have a list of filters that recreate the whole list of datas of the virtualscroll. Unfortunately I have never been able to have the whole VS red-drawn properly. the design is a list of 5 columns.

It alsways works great on first draw, but when changing the filters it always fails to display the Vs properly.

So I decided to remove the VS altogether and recreate a new one with *ngIf and a timeout. My directive encapsulating the Vs does get destroyed (ngOnDestroy is properly called). But once redrawn the list of empty (no items are shown), even after a resize. The inner property _init of the VS is false.

I have a plunkr that demonstrate the bug:
https://plnkr.co/edit/8eN0N7

```
reload () {
      this.killVS = true;
      setTimeout ( () => {
        this.killVS = false;
      }
    , 3000); 
    }
```

(when clicking on ‘reload’ the list displays empty)

If anyone encountered the same problem I would love to get some help…

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want or if you want to destroy the DOM node but if you replace your `*ngIf` with `[hidden]="killVS"` it hides the list and shows it again after 3secs.

Comment: I updated the plunkr to use `hidden`, and then change the dataset. As you can see the same problem happens....

Comment: Even worse, the virtualscroll just fails badly...

Comment: Try moving the hidden directive from ion-content to the ion-list.